# Cannot get Roboguice Astroboy example to work

Tags: android, roboguice

I've spent hours trying to get Roboguice to work, but with no success. My latest effort involved trying to get the Astroboy example to work but I've run into problems after (eventually) getting it to deploy.

This is a summary of my steps performed:

1. Installed a clean copy of Apache Maven 3
2. Installed a clean copy of the Android SDK and downloaded all available platforms
3. Installed and ran the Maven Android SDK Deployer so all artifacts were downloaded etc
4. Downloaded a clone of the Astroboy example
5. Performed mvn clean install to build roboguice and astroboy. Test failed as I didn't have a platform 9 downloaded. No idea why it was referencing what seems to be an obsolete API so I ran this command to download even obsolete APIs: android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force
6. Performed mvn clean install again and it built successfully this time
7. Performed mvn android:deploy and android:run. Successful except with this warning:

   [WARNING]
   [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
   org.roboguice:astroboy:apk:2.0-SNAPSHOT
   [WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at org.roboguice:roboguice-aggregator ins
   tead of org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent, please verify your project structure @ line
   104, column 13
   [WARNING]
   [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
   he stability of your build.
   [WARNING]
   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
   g such malformed projects.
   [WARNING]
8. Ran the application and get this error now:

   ```
   11-22 03:45:35.470: E/AndroidRuntime(2437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start activity         ComponentInfo{org.roboguice.astroboy/org.roboguice.astroboy.activity.AstroboyMaster Console}: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
   ```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I've followed all the instructions but have no idea what the issue is now.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the ACL library to your build path. That's the android.support.v4. It can be found in your sdk folder under extras > android > compatibility. If its not there, download it with the SDK manager tool.

Comment: OK I got this to work after adding this dependency to my astroboy pom:<dependency><groupId>android.support</groupId><artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId><version>r4</version></dependency>

Comment: I'll investigate why this dependency is necessary: http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=152

Comment: Anyone have any idea why it was looking for the platform-9 API? Where is this set in my config?